# How to rewrite url in html document in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

What I try to achieve is to rewrite

```
http://www.mydomain.com/subject/
```

to

```
http://mylocalhost:8080/ (= tomcat).
```

Purely for forwarding I use in httpd:

```
ProxyPass /subject/ http://mylocalhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /subject/ http://mylocalhost:8080/
```

This works, except for the content of the html documents. IOW: all the links in the returned html still contain

```
http://mylocalhost:8080/...
```

My attempts with mod_rewrite haven't been very successful, so my question is: how do I rewrite the actual document contents?

The tomcat app doesn't give the possibility to alter the baseurl.

Comment: Do you use hard coded links (complete url with servername etc) or relative in your html document?

Comment: on the Tomcat side the url's are fully qualified, with servername. Unfortunatly that is not something I can alter (since it's not my code that's running on Tomcat).

Comment: Usually Tomcat will rewrite its URLs based on X-Forwarded headers. If the developer has literally hardcoded `http://mylocalhost:8080` then that needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do an *internal* = not visible redirect. Go [here for a clean explanation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/remapping.html).

Comment: I've seen this site but I still have no clue how to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For situations where you need to reverse-proxy an application that doesn't cooperate and cannot be updated, there is [`mod_proxy_html`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html).

This will buffer any returned HTML documents and rewrite links inside them.

```
ProxyPass /subject/ http://mylocalhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /subject/ http://mylocalhost:8080/
ProxyHTMLEnable On
```

It has various other directives to control precisely what and how it changes.